# empty or nil field filter not working for elastic search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I am trying to create an ES query where 3 things must be true: a boolean field must be true, a search term must match a field, and third filed must be null.  Here's my query in YML (I'm using mongoid-elasticsearch)

```
:query:
  :filtered:
    :filter:
      :bool:
        :must:
        - :term:
            :qualified: true
        - :term:
            :name: mukluk
        - :missing:
            :field: :location_ids
            :existence: true
            :null_value: true
```

In this query "name" is the name of a field.

This results in zero hits.

If I remove the last key (missing), the query works fine.  Here's the actual record in JSON (this is the actual elasticsearch JSON that gets returned when removing the missing filter, so you can see that location_ids is in fact nil):

```
{
  "took"=> 1,
  "timed_out"=> false,
  "_shards"=> {
    "total"=> 5,
    "successful"=> 5,
    "failed"=> 0
  },
  "hits"=> {
    "total"=> 1,
    "max_score"=> 1.0,
    "hits"=> [
      {
        "_index"=> "items",
        "_type"=> "item",
        "_id"=> "5480b53c73d5495ce600062b",
        "_score"=> 1.0,
        "_source"=> {
          "name"=> "FitFlop mukluk (black)",
          "description"=> "FitFlop mukluk (black)",
          "qualified"=> true,
          "retailer_id"=> "5470a7f273d549817c1882de",
          "location_ids"=> nil
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

See how location_ids is nil?  How do I get this to be part of the query?

btw, here's the body json of the actual query that gets submitted:

```
{
  \"query\": {
    \"filtered\": {
      \"filter\": {
        \"bool\": {
          \"must\": [
            {
              \"term\": {
                \"qualified\": true
              }
            },
            {
              \"term\": {
                \"name\": \"mukluk\"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  \"size\": 200,
  \"from\": 0
}
```

UPDATE:

Here's the output of the failed query:

```
{
  "took"=> 1,
  "timed_out"=> false,
  "_shards"=> {
    "total"=> 5,
    "successful"=> 5,
    "failed"=> 0
  },
  "hits"=> {
    "total"=> 0,
    "max_score"=> nil,
    "hits"=> []
  }
}
```

And here's the mapping:

```
index_mappings: {
  name: {
    type: 'multi_field',
    fields: {
      name: {
        type: 'string',
        analyzer: 'snowball'
      },
      description: {
        type: 'string', 
        analyzer: 'snowball'
      },
      qualfied: {
        type: 'boolean', 
        index: :not_analyzed
      },
      location_ids: {
        type: 'string', 
        index: :not_analyzed
      }
    }
  },
  tags: {
    type: 'string', 
    include_in_all: false
  },
  wrapper: :load
}
```

Comment: would it be possible to post the mapping and the actual json response ?

Comment: Sure, here's the output: [code] {"took"=>1, "timed_out"=>false, "_shards"=>{"total"=>5, "successful"=>5, "failed"=>0}, "hits"=>{"total"=>0, "max_score"=>nil, "hits"=>[]}}[/code]

Comment: @keety updated, thanks in advance, i am suspecting you're on to something with the mapping, b/c i see now it's a string even though the data is an array of strings.